# How to group the different values of same field

Tags: mysql

I have written

```
 SELECT DISTINCT r.id_destination
               , lo.location1
               , lo.location2
               , lo.destination
               , lo.zip
               , ld.id_field
               , da.identification entity
               , da.data
            FROM pl_records r
            JOIN pl_records_detail rd 
              ON r.id_order = rd.id_order 
       LEFT JOIN pl_attribue at 
              ON rd.product_attribute_id = at.id_product_attribute 
       LEFT JOIN pl_profile pr 
              ON at.id_attribute = pr.id_attribute 
            JOIN pl_location lo 
              ON r.id_address_delivery = lo.id_address 
            JOIN pl_situation si 
              ON r.current_state = si.id_order_state 
       LEFT JOIN pl_location_detail  
              ON r.id_cart = ld.id_cart 
       LEFT JOIN pl_data da 
              ON ld.id_field = da.id_field
           WHERE r.id_record = 6
```

It returns the output which gets repeated because of the fields " entity" and "data" as they contain many values!

```
id_destination location1         location2 destination zip id_field entity data
            55 east coast street ON        CN          454       28     89 Please process it with safe standards      
            55 east coast street ON        CN          454       28     90 Payment will be COD
            55 east coast street ON        CN          454       28     78 updates not necessary
            55 east coast street ON        CN          454       28     92 no withdrawal of details
            55 east coast street ON        CN          454       28     99 added records
```

How is it possible to prevent the duplication of values?  or is it possible to How to group the different values of the last two fields

Comment: But they're not really duplicates, are they? The `data` is different each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `group_concat()`?

```
SELECT r.id_destination, lo.location1, lo.location2, lo.destination, lo.zip,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ld.id_field) as id_fields,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT da.identification) AS entities
da.data
FROM pl_records r JOIN
     pl_records_detail rd
     ON r.id_order = rd.id_order LEFT JOIN 
     pl_attribue at
     ON rd.product_attribute_id = at.id_product_attribute LEFT JOIN
     pl_profile p
     ON at.id_attribute = pr.id_attribute JOIN
     pl_location lo
     ON r.id_address_delivery = lo.id_address JOIN
     pl_situation si
     ON r.current_state = si.id_order_state LEFT JOIN
     pl_location_detail
     ON r.id_cart = ld.id_cart LEFT JOIN
     pl_data da
     on ld.id_field = da.id_field
WHERE r.id_record = 6
GROUP BY r.id_destination, lo.location1, lo.location2, lo.destination, lo.zip
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Now I am getting to you how to use group_concat() in the query. Will apply and hope the result should be fine. Thanks again